# Buying Isobutane/propane canisters in Reykjavik near Laugavegur?

Tags: shopping, iceland, camping, gear, reykjavik

I’m flying in for a backpacking trip and would like to pick up a gas canaster near my hotel before leaving the city. Where can you get isobutane/propane mix canisters (i.e. for Jetboil or MSR Pocket Rocket) in Reykjavik, within walking distance of Laugavegur.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question per se, but in my experience grocery stores in Iceland are more like a "general store". Like in the same aisle as the milk, you might also find windscreen wipers, kids toys, and knitting wool. I wasn't specifically looking for cooking gas, but if you ask they'll either have it or be able to tell you where to find it.

Comment: Voting to reopen: question is not about price-shopping, but about whether/where these bottles are available at all. Considering those canisters are mostly/exclusively used for travel, it's a travel and not a shopping question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't speak from personal experience, but according to [this old reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/VisitingIceland/comments/4eo89x/can_i_buy_fuel_for_a_jet_boil_in_iceland/), these canisters are readily available at most gas stations in Iceland. [Iceland Camping Equipment](https://www.iceland-camping-equipment.com/collections/iceland-stove-gas-fuel-rental/products/gas-canister-fuel-iceland) also says they can sell them to you at their shop in the BSÍ, the main bus terminal in Reykjavík, which is a fairly short walk from the Laugavegur and which you may pass through anyway on your way to and from the city.