# Can I bring a butane/propane bottle on the MS Norröna ferry?

Tags: ferries, iceland, faroe-islands

Can I bring a small camping fuel bottle (such as [Primus Power gas](https://primus.us/products/power-gas)) on the Smyril Line ferry MS Norröna between Hirtshals, Tórshavn, and Seyðisfjörður?  I find conflicting information on the [Smyril line website](https://www.smyril-line.com/customer-service/good-to-know?tab=msnorr%c3%b6na):

> **Liquid gas on board MS Norröna**
> It is allowed to bring max 20 liters of extra liquid gas on board MS Norröna. The tanks need to be of steel and need to be approved for the purpose.

That reads like a yes — under pressure, the gas in the Primus bottle is liquid, the container is made of steel, and presumably approved for the purpose.  But further down, the same page also says:

> **Propane-gas on board MS Norröna**
> Extra gas tanks are only allowed to bring on board, if they are empty.

There is propane in the mixture, and the bottle is not empty — so this reads like a no.

The two instructions appear to contradict each other.
What applies to a small camping fuel bottle?

Comment: If the answer turns out to be "no", or you don't get an answer, see [this previous question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/177502/buying-isobutane-propane-canisters-in-reykjavik-near-laugavegur) referencing [a reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/VisitingIceland/comments/4eo89x/can_i_buy_fuel_for_a_jet_boil_in_iceland/) in which it is alleged that these canisters are available at most gas stations in Iceland.

Comment: @mlc Yes, that would probably work; I suppose I can buy one in Seyðisfjörður or Egilsstaðir.  I'm also interested in a nearly-3-day stopover at the Faroe Isles, though, and it'd be a bit wasteful to buy a canister just for that.  But possible.

Comment: I agree that the wording is difficult to understand, but can it be that the first paragraph actually refers to autogas (LPG) as a vehicle fuel and the second paragraph to propane gas tanks as found in e.g. camper vans or other recreational vehicles? If you look at the entire second paragraph, it  starts with referring to vehicles.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I wonder if the [Icelandic](https://www.smyrilline.is/velkomin-a-%C3%BEjonustusi%C3%B0u/hagnytar-upplysingar) or [Faroese](https://www.smyrilline.fo/kundataenastan/gott-at-vita) versions are any clearer.  Although it seems the page says different things in different languages; the Dutch version doesn't mention gas at all.

Comment: The Icelandic page contains more or less the same text as the English page. The only significant difference is that the title of the second paragraph is (in Icelandic) "Gas containers mounted in vehicles" instead of "Propane-gas on board MS Norröna". The Faeroese and Danish pages agree with each other, but have a completely different text. These pages say that gas containers in vehicles are allowed, but you need a sticker on the vehicle's wind screen informing about that and that the gas supply to the vehicle/RV must be turned off before driving onboard the ferry.